# Program Advice Directx with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx

```
What I am using:
    Visual Studio 2010
    Windows Media Center
    Language C#
```

**The Program**
A part of my program needs to display movies by their covers and be able to scroll through them, much like netflix. I was told that directx would be good to accomplish this.  Basically I just want it to be easy to view, use, and flow nicely.

Help?
Any Ideas as to what to use.  (I was also looking into writing it as a pluggin for windows media player, but i read somewhere you can only have html based menus?)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks
-Scott

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/scobleizer/Charlie-Owen-Your-first-Media-CenterVista-application-and-a-look-at-their-secret-room
The problem with using Direct3D for an application like this is that you have to start creating your own window manager.

You don't have the default events available to you and you will have to basically create your own GUI which is easier in WPF as those events and helpers exist.